# cant submit apps to the app store xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have down loaded Xcode 5 preview

I can not submit my apps to the app store using the preview version, if I try I get a message saying that the app store wont accept apps from this version of Xcode.

if I use the older version of Xcode (v4.5 i think) then it comes up with an error saying use a more recent version of Xcode.

I have tried uninstalling the preview but to no success, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the latest release version of Xcode, Xcode 4.6?

Comment: The preview/beta currently seems to be under NDA and thus should be discussed elsewhere (Apple's developer forums).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have had the XCode 5 installed their exists two pathes to XCode. I had the problem that the fileMerge-Tool exists twice and it is not working. I solved that by removing the XCode 5 installation and switch back to the correct installed xCode version with:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

That switches the context back to the origin installed XCode.

Docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation you will see that XCode 5 and iOS7 are currently under Beta and apps built using these cannot be submitted to the app store.

The current version of XCode is 4.6.3 you need to download this from the Mac app store and submit your apps using this

Answer (score 1):

As Adam explains, you'll have to Install Xcode 4.

If you are using Mountain Lion, you can't Install Xcode 4 out of the box"

You can install Xcode 4 by temporary editing the System Version.

1. go to /system/library/coreservices
2. Find SystemVersion.plist and open it
3. Change the two bottom numbers (10.9) to 10.8.4 and save
4. Install Xcode 4
5. Change those numbers back to 10.9 and save.

Hope this helped :)